# How to Decode Arbitrum's L1 Batch Transaction Data Retrieved from Etherscan?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, brotli

I'm trying to decode Arbitrum's L1 batch [data](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x69af0271f846359115aadc0e5e1e004864ac40bf6d7c7cc148b5128cb7a76d96) fetched from Etherscan. I'm using `ethers.js` to convert the hexadecimal data to a `Uint8Array` and then attempting to decompress it with a Brotli library in Node.js. However, I'm encountering an error during the decompression process.

**Code Snippet:**

```js
const ethers = require('ethers');
const brotli = require('brotli');

let data = '0x...'; // Hexadecimal string from Etherscan (the `data` in `bytes` under Input Data)
let bytesData = ethers.getBytes(data);
let decompressedData = brotli.decompress(bytesData);
```

**Error:**

```
Error: [ReadHuffmanCodeLengths] space = -1024
```

I'm looking for guidance on:

1. Correctly converting the data for Brotli decompression.
2. Handling specifics of Arbitrum's batch data format.
3. Resolving the decompression error in Node.js.

Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated!